# React - Convert class component to functional component for session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, react-hooks, next.js

In react application, I am trying to do auto logout for inactive user(session) by referring https://medium.com/tinyso/how-to-detect-inactive-user-to-auto-logout-by-using-idle-timeout-in-javascript-react-angular-and-b6279663acf2

Now If I try to change class component's code to functional code, it will not work as it was working before.

Class component code will get it from https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-dream-w1cyc?from-embed

Function component code as is below

index.js

```
const IdleTimer = ({ timeout, onTimeout, onExpired }) => {
  const expiredTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('_expiredTime'), 10)
  if (expiredTime > 0 && expiredTime < Date.now()) {
    onExpired()
    return
  }
  let timeoutTracker = null

  const interval = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (expiredTime < Date.now()) {
        if (onTimeout) {
          onTimeout()
          cleanUp()
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  const updateExpiredTime = (e) => {
    if (timeoutTracker) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutTracker)
    }
    timeoutTracker = setTimeout(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('_expiredTime', Date.now() + timeout * 1000)
    }, 300)
  }

  const startInterval = () => {
    updateExpiredTime()
    interval()
  }

  const tracker = () => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateExpiredTime)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', updateExpiredTime)
    window.addEventListener('keydown', updateExpiredTime)
  }

  tracker()
  startInterval()

  const cleanUp = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('_expiredTime')
    clearInterval(interval)
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', updateExpiredTime)
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', updateExpiredTime)
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', updateExpiredTime)
  }
}
export default IdleTimer
```

app.js,

```
const [isTimeout, setIsTimeout] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const timer = IdleTimer({
    timeout: 20, //expire after 20 seconds
    onTimeout: () => {
      setIsTimeout(true)
    },
    onExpired: () => {
      setIsTimeout(true)
    },
  })

  return () => {
    timer.cleanUp()
  }
}, [])

if (isAuthenticated && isTimeout) {
  logout()
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue. I want functional component without `useEffect()`.

Comment: You need `useEffect` to start the side-effect of the timer and to cleanup any active listeners when this component unmounts. What exactly is this issue?

Comment: Currently, the issue is `isTimeout` is not updating. Also if I try to use `useEffect()` other feature(in application) will not work because of `events` which will trigger every second under `setInterval`.

Comment: `isTimeout` is working in your codesandbox, so the issue you have isn't clear to me. Is something other than toggling true after 10 seconds inactivity supposed to occur? What other features are you referring to? I don't understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: In codesandbox everything is working but when I convert to functional component it will not work.

Comment: Convert what to a functional component though? In your sandbox, `App` already is a functional component. Are you trying to convert the IdleTimer class into a React component? `IdleTimer` isn't a React component.

Comment: Ah, I see now, you are trying to convert the IdleTimer class into a function, but for what purpose? Your question makes less sense now since what you are trying to convert isn't a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With App from codesandbox which you send below function works as expected.

```js
const IdleTimerFun = ({ timeout, onTimeout, onExpired }) => {
  let timeoutTracker = null;
  let interval = null;

  const expiredTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("_expiredTime"), 10);
  if (expiredTime > 0 && expiredTime < Date.now()) {
    onExpired();
    return;
  }

  const startInterval = () => {
    updateExpiredTime();

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      const expiredTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("_expiredTime"), 10);
      if (expiredTime < Date.now()) {
        if (onTimeout) {
          onTimeout();
          cleanUp();
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  const updateExpiredTime = () => {
    if (timeoutTracker) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutTracker);
    }
    timeoutTracker = setTimeout(() => {
      localStorage.setItem("_expiredTime", Date.now() + timeout * 1000);
    }, 300);
  };

  const tracker = () => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", updateExpiredTime);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", updateExpiredTime);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", updateExpiredTime);
  };

  const cleanUp = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("_expiredTime");
    clearInterval(interval);
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", updateExpiredTime);
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", updateExpiredTime);
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", updateExpiredTime);
  };

  tracker();
  startInterval();
};

export default IdleTimerFun;
```